# Using present tense instead of past tense

Tags: tense

In the text below

> Suicides liked the bridge. The cop didn't think of that until he saw the man get out of the car, walk slowly along the footpath at the edge, and put a hand on a rail.

Why the writer didn't say

"Suicides liked the bridge. The cop didn't think of that until he saw the man **got out** of the car, **walked** slowly along the footpath at the edge, and put a hand on a rail."

Why the writer has used the present tenses instead of past tenses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct form. The verbs *get*, *walk*, *put* aren't present-tense forms but *unmarked infinitives* (*unmarked* means they aren't 'marked' with *to*). That is one of the two verbforms<sup>†</sup> which are permitted in clauses which act as complements to most verbs of perception, like *see*, *hear*, *notice*.

It is sometimes difficult to distinguish an unmarked infinitive from the plain present form, because there is only one verb in which they are different: *be*, whose plain present form is *are*.

But when, as in your example, the verb's subject calls for a 3d-person singular form, it is easy to tell the difference. If these were present forms, the sentence would read

> ... he saw the man **gets** out of the car, **walks** slowly along the footpath at the edge, and **puts** a hand on a rail.

---

<sup>†</sup> The other one is the present participle; you could also write

> ... he saw the man **getting** out of the car, **walking** slowly along the footpath at the edge, and **putting** a hand on a rail.

But the participle is usually used to say what someone is doing at a particular moment, not a series of things done; so the infinitive is preferred here.

Comment: Also note that "the man" is an object here, not a subject. One would say "I saw him get out of the car", not "I saw he get out of the car".

Comment: @TannerSwett This comment is too important for me. Thanks a lot. I always wondered such structure in English.

Comment: @TannerSwett Strictly speaking it's a subject of the following verbs, and it is the clause(s) which are the object; but in these cases it takes the object form (if it has one).

Comment: I agree the unmarked infinitive is more *likely*, but I can't say OP's past tense alternative is inherently invalid. I can easily assume a deleted ***that*** after ***saw***, and although it looks just a little awkward in OP's exact context, I've no doubt it would pass without comment in some structurally comparable contexts. But I'm fairly sure present tense could never work, even in a contrived context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I hadn't thought of a 'null complementizer' there. You're right, though if that were the case I would expect a past perfect: "... saw (that) the man *had got(ten)* out of the car, walked..., put...*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Stoney,  ... but the verb *SEE* used with a finite clause has a slightly different meaning. It means something like *understood* rather than that the subject watched an action while it was happening. Consider *I saw that he had eaten the pie*. :)

Comment: @Araucaria: To ***see** [that] something happened* can also mean to ***ensure*** it happened, as in *"We had an early start in the morning, so I saw [that] he went to bed as soon as he had eaten the pie"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely. Nice observation. Hadn't thought of that one too! :)

Comment: @Araucaria: *"I see,"* said the blind man (and from personal experience I can confirm that blind people *do* say that! :)