# Choosing the wrong sentence in the following sentences

Tags: comparison

Here is an English grammar question from a certain English learning material I bought at the book store.

I am very confused over this.

It is said there is only one answer from the five sentences, however, I think there is no answer. All the sentences below seem grammatically fine to me.

I hope you would carefully check it out and tell me what the answer is and why, please.

> **Q. Choose the wrong sentence in the following sentences.**
>
> 1. Deep-sea habitats are as varied as those on land.
> 2. Writing a novel is two times as difficult as I think.
> 3. He looks three times as happy as I had seen.
> 4. I love her as much as you.
> 5. Several excuses are always less convincing than one.

Thank you for reading. Take care of yourself.

Comment: @CopperKettle Why delete your answer? I can't upvote or agree with it while it is "deleted". By the way, I agree with you in that #3 was the one that struck me as being the worst one in the list. :)

Comment: Is there an explanation in the book? Most books should have one. Anyway, #3 is not grammatical. I cannot tell you why, else I would write an answer. However, all the rest, including #2 are grammatical. For a check, write each sentence as a question. In the case of Number 2: *Is writing a novel two times as difficult as I think?* You can also answer the question: *No, writing a novel is not two times as difficult as I think.*

Answer (score 4):

> Q. Choose the wrong sentence in the following sentences.
>
> 1. Deep-sea habitats are as varied as those on land.
> 2. Writing a novel is two times as difficult as I think.
> 3. He looks three times as happy as I had seen.
> 4. I love her as much as you.
> 5. Several excuses are always less convincing than one.

I think ***option #3***, *"He looks three times as happy as I had seen"*, is probably, or should be, the "wrong sentence".

For it seems to be missing the 2nd time reference point in its comparison of when he looked happy. The other four options appear to be fine.

---

**LONG VERSION:**
Here I'll go and explain a bit more why the individual options seem to be okay or not.

#### Option #1. *Deep-sea habitats are as varied as those on land.*

This appears to be fine. Two terms are being compared: "the variety of deep-sea habitats" versus "the variety of land habitats".

#### Option #2. *Writing a novel is two times as difficult as I think.*

This appears to be fine. Two terms are being compared: "the (actual) difficulty in writing a novel" versus "the difficulty that I think it takes to write a novel".

A possible context:

- If I was a young writer, I might think that I ought to be able to easily write a sci-fi novel in a year, but my parents might shake their heads in disagreement and say that that would take two years at least. And so, when I talk to a friend about this, I might say to that friend, *"Writing a novel is two times as difficult as I think. That's what my parents keep telling me."*

As a standalone sentence, option #2's sentence works too: the actual writing of a novel is X difficult, and I think writing a novel is Y difficult, and X is equal to 2Y.

#### Option #3. *He looks three times as happy as I had seen.*

This one seems to be malformed. And it seems to be the most awkward of all the options in the list.

Its problem seems to be that it doesn't mention within the second term (the comparative clause) a 2nd time that is being compared against. The 1st time that is being used in the comparison could be now, as in *"He **now** looks happy",* but there is no 2nd time of when he looked happy which could be used in the comparison. That is, in other words: He now (at time #1) looks X happy, and he used to (at time #2) look Y happy, and X is equal to 3Y -- but there is no mentioning of when that time #2 was.

Option #3's sentence could be tweaked into something that could work, such as *"He looks three times as happy as when I had seen him last."*

#### Option #4. *I love her as much as you.*

This appears to be fine, but perhaps it could be ambiguous as to how it should be interpreted, and context will probably disambiguate it. It could possibly be interpreted in two ways. One (1st) interpretation is,

1. *I love her as much as you **do**.*

where the two terms are: "I love her" vs "You love her". Another possible (2nd) interpretation is,

2. *I love her as much as **I love** you.*

where the two terms are: "I love her" vs "I love you". This 2nd interpretation of option #4 is structured similar to,

- *"I love cookies as much as cupcakes."*

Aside: Sometimes comparative constructions can be full of ambiguity, e.g. *"She phoned Angela more often than Liz"*, which can be interpreted with the 2nd term being either "she phoned Liz" or as "Liz phoned her". (Example borrowed from *CGEL* page 1112, [20.v])

#### Option #5. *Several excuses are always less convincing than one.*

This appears to be fine. Two terms are being compared: "the convincing power of several excuses" versus "the convincing power of one excuse".

Comment: I think this has to do with what material is elipted in each case. Essentially, the same auxiliary verb (maybe different persons etc, even different tenses, but the same verb) and the same complements (including further verbs) need to be used in each case unless they are specified, it seems to me. In (3) the auxiliaries are different, and we don't automatically reconstruct the sentence well. The verbs are different too (*look* and *see*).

Comment: @Araucaria I also think a big problem is that we don't know what the 2nd term is for comparison: is it a 2nd time event, or is it the set of all time events in the past. That is, is what is missing the word "last" (or something similar) or the word "ever"; e.g. *"He looks three times as happy as (when) I had **last** seen **him**",* or *"He looks (at least) three times as happy as I had **ever** seen **him**"*. That's what I'm currently seeing it as; and as you pointed out, having different verbs in there doesn't help the situation, either. :)

Comment: I'm still wondering... I think your solutions to #3  allow *look* to be reintroduced:*as [he looked] when I last saw him* or *as I had ever seen him [look]*. Not sure... Very interesting question...

Comment: It may have to with that you must explicitly state the object of *see* if you say *see.*

Comment: @F.E. Have been, erm [glomming](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37072/he-saw-it-stop-and-his-son-get-out/43697#43697), as recommended. Fancy casting a beady eye?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that sentence 3 might not be right:

> 3. He looks three times as happy as I had seen.

It uses the Past Perfect but there's no another past-time reference in the sentence. And probably it is wrong to end the sentence so abruptly, making no explicit comparison.

I would transform it thus:

> He look**ed** three times as happy as I had seen *him look before*.

Now we have a "Past Simple - Past Perfect" sentence comparing a person's past condition with his condition in an earlier past, and a more explicit comparison clause.

Note: I'm a non-native speaker, so it's only a guess. I might be wrong.

I googled in books for "as I had seen", and [found a sentence](https://books.google.ru/books?id=iDQQhRsYMEEC&lpg=PT41&dq=%22as%20i%20had%20seen%22&hl=ru&pg=PT41#v=onepage&q=%22as%20i%20had%20seen%22&f=false) with a comparable structure:

> Auntie Lolo **was** as beautiful as I **had seen** her in my vision, and I remembered that..

The same [sequence of tenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English): Past Simple - Past Perfect.

Comment: I believe you are incorrect actually - the other time reference in 3. is actually the present (implied by verb tense of look) and the past perfect is appropriate. It is an abrupt ending, but it is none-the-less idiomatic and grammatically correct.

Comment: @bruisedreed - thank you for the comment! I thought that the Past Perfect is only okay when the other time reference is also in the past. But I could be incorrect. It was an interesting question to think upon. I'll keep my answer for some time, then scrap it if it gets downvoted.

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert (I'm just a native speaker who volunteers to help ELS learners, I haven't studied English at University or anything like that), but I believe past perfect can even be employed in the context of talking about future events - eg. "What you don't want is to find yourself next week thinking 'If only I had studied harder.'"

Comment: @bruisedreed: I also lack a formal degree in English but I've been reading some chapters on conditional constructions in Quirk et al. recently (chapter 15.35) and your "If only I had studied.." seems to be part of a conditional "If only I **had studied** harder, I **would not have been** so sorry." The second ("sorry") part, the "matrix clause", is implied, and it does contain a "past perfective modal" construction. And the whole conditional is a "direct speech" clause, so it does not have to agree in tense terms with the main clause "What you don't want.." (sorry for the jargon)

Comment: I can't argue with your analysis, but I don't quite understand how it actually legitimizes your previous statement that "the past perfect is only okay when the other time reference is also in the past." I believe sentence 3. becomes a well-formed sentence as it originally was merely by the addition of the adverb 'previously'. As this is idiomatically implied, the sentence should be considered legitimate. Anyways I'm done - I respect your ability to argue your case well even if I don't agree with it :)

Comment: I agree with you in that #3 *"He looks three times as happy as I had seen."* seems to be the most awkward of the options in the list. Comparative constructions are perhaps the trickiest grammar stuff to explain, and I tend to avoid doing that, perhaps because I'm lazy and all. #3 is awkward because it doesn't mention within the comparative clause a 2nd time that is being compared against. For instance, "He looks three times as happy as when I had seen him last." :)

Comment: The options #1, #5 seem to be fine to me, and #4 seems probably okay, maybe. (Option #4 might be similar to the textbook ambiguous thingie, where perhaps it would be preferable to put the "do" in it, e.g. *"I love her as much as you do."* But the original #4 is not as bad as #3, imo.) It took me a while, but I was able to convince myself that option #2 might possibly be feasible in an appropriate context: *"Writing a novel is two times as difficult as I think. That's what my parents keep telling me."* And so, I was left with #3 as being the worst of the bunch. :)

Comment: *"but there's no another past-time reference in the sentence. And probably it is wrong to end the sentence so abruptly, making no explicit comparison."* <== I think you nailed the problem with option #3 right there! :)

Comment: @F.E. Shouldn't the context you imagine for #2 modify it to: "'Writing a novel is two times as difficult as *you* think' - that's what my parents keep telling me."? In any event, if it is that reliant on context to be properly parsed, can it really be regarded as a grammatical sentence in it's own right? I don't see how you can really get around properly disassociating the author/speaker/thinker of the phrase from the "I" to avoid a contradiction.

Comment: @bruisedreed If I was a young writer, I might think that I ought to be able to easily write a sci-fi novel in a year, but my parents might shake their heads in disagreement and say that would take two years at least. And so, when I talk to a friend about this, I might say to that friend, *"Writing a novel is two times as difficult as I think. That's what my parents keep telling me."* -- As a standalone, option #2's sentence seems to work too: I think writing a novel is X difficult, and the actual writing of a novel is Y difficult, and Y is equal to 2X.

Comment: As I commented to @F.E.it may have to do with the fact that if you state *see* you must explicitly state its object.

Answer (score 1):

2. Is incorrect - using the incorrect tense for think makes this statement internally inconsistent (ie. a contradiction). It should read:

> 2. Writing a novel is twice as difficult as I had thought.

3. & 4. (and arguably 5.) are not well-formed sentences semantically, but I would not go as far as to say that they are not grammatical.

Comment: I know that you are not required to do so, but I would greatly appreciate that if you are going to down-vote that you kindly explain why.

Comment: It seems that I was wrong after all. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle Did Snailboa say that the sentence 3 was okay? Where can I find the "chat printouts"? How do you know that the native speakers voted for the answer of  bruised reed and voted against your answer? What if Native speakers of Hindi voted for the answer of bruised reed? :)

Comment: @Humbulani - chat transcripts are *[here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19097632#19097632)*.

Comment: @Humbulani I don't recall saying sentence #3 was "okay", just that it didn't have one particular problem.

Comment: @snailboat - then I must've misunderstood your remark in the chat (and kept my answer scrapped until FE nudged me to revive it), sorry.

Comment: @snailboat, sorry. I've just repeated that misstatement after CopperKettle.

Comment: -1 I'm finding out that writing a novel is twice as difficult as I think.

Comment: @CarSmack Your reconstruction is not ok: firstly dropping the first phrase is not optional - it can't be simply inferred; secondly, already the thought process of the author has changed - no longer can he use 'think' about what he previously assessed the difficulty of the novel as being, it was what he 'thought'.

Comment: Of course, I disagree. Turn the sentence into a question:  *Is writing a novel two times as difficult as I think?* That is fine. You can also answer the question: *No, writing a novel is not two times as difficult as I think.*